# emacs24.3 with builtin org 7.9 need org-reload to have compiled org-mode 8

Tags: org-mode, emacs24

I installed emacs 24.3.2 from git.
In this version there is org 7.9 released.
Next I installed last org-mode from git and compiled it (make autoload).

Now I need to launch org-reload to have the latest version (8) else I have the builtin version (7.9).

So I had in init.el:
`(call-interactively 'org-reload)`

returns:

`Cannot open load file: ob.el`

So I guess I have to call it after org is loaded (`add-hook 'after-init-hook`).
But the same error appears.

So I don't know how to have the last org-mode installed on my current emacs24.3.2 which already have a builtin org-mode.

Comment: Make sure that the newest org is on the top of your load path.

Comment: could you explain the code to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to eval this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/path/to/git/org-mode")
(org-reload)
```

Comment: thanks change by `"~/path/to/git/org-mode∕lisp"` and `"~/path/to/git/org-mode∕contrib/lisp"`